# Python web frameworks: HTML server-side templates and duplication of code

Tags: python, html, web, template-engine

I'm experimenting Python web frameworks and HTML templates. The concept seems restricted, compared to generating entire HTML code on the fly. For instance, to generate a combo box, I found the following Django templating example:

```
<select id="{{ item.name }}" name="{{ item.name }}">
{% for choice in item.choices %}
  {% ifequal item.value choice %}
  <option value="{{ choice }}" selected>{{ choice }}</A>
  {% else %}
  <option value="{{ choice }}">{{ choice }}</A>
  {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

The ifequal statement duplicates entire  code just to add a "selected" attribute to the selected option. It seems to me this becomes a burden in HTML tags with several attributes and which some few attributes exist or not depending on a condition. Is the above snippet a bad usage of templating? Is there a better way to implement the combo box using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be written in a single line in this way.

```
<option value="{{ choice }}" {% ifequal item.value choice %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ choice }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. I still think that generating html code on the fly is easier than this. You could even modularize it (eg a create_combobox(options, selected_option) method). It seems to me web developers prefer to use HTML templates though, it is just a matter of opinion or I am missing something here?

Comment: Well its better to keep our server side code lighter. So if you will try to create template code on fly will just increase your server load. That's why i think every one prefer to handle many thinks at template level.